# How to exit from snap watch command?

Tags: bash, snap, kill

I launched a `snap install` command from one bash terminal and I wanted to see the installation progress in another terminal.

I first ran `snap changes` to figure out the ID value to watch for, then ran `snap watch <ID>`. Installation progress showed as expected.

However, when I do `CTRL-C` or `q`, the `watch` command won't quit. Instead it just piles up another watch progress line on the console.

How am I supposed to quit watching, *without* interrupting the actual installation process?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I am currently aware of is forceful termination of the `watch` task. To kill `snap watch` send `SIGQUIT` by pressing  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

Note that it should only terminate watching, not the action it watches, so. i.e. download task should continue (which you can verify with `snap changes` or `snap tasks <ID>`).